# Why the definition of a limit of a function can't contain $\left | L-f(x) \right | < \epsilon$ instead of $\left | f(x)-L\right | < \epsilon$?

Tags: limits, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

The both expressions express that the distance between the two numbers $f(x)$ and $L$ should be smaller than $\epsilon$. What is the problem if we rephrase the definition in this way?

Comment: There is no problem, it just is more convenient

Comment: @OfekGillon Why is it more convenient?

Comment: I think it is more convenient when you take your function you don't need to worry to put a minus sign next to each expression

Comment: If you think of subtraction as an operation on the minuend (the first operand) by the subtrahend (second operand) then $f(x)-L$ conveys the idea that $f(x)$ is the variable quantity and $L$ is fixed. You can think of $-L$ as a little machine that operates on the minuend. The machine answers the question: How close to the limit is $f(x)$?, which is what's wanted. Also just by virtue of $f(x)$ appearing first, the focus is placed on it, rather than $L$. Correspondingly, in the definition of limit, $f(x)$ is the focus.

Answer (score 3):

It can, there is no problem of writing it the other way, I think its more of a custom.

Comment: Why is it the case?

Comment: $f(x)\to L$ kind of looks like $f(x)-L.$